# Spring property place holder config needs to be replaced dynamically during runtime

Tags: java, spring

i have a property class holder config in spring

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${appConfig}" />
```

There are three configs in my class path  dev.properties, qa.properties and prod.properties

i need to pass the appConfig and it should be replaced with the values what i pass dynamically during runtime

when i do this   java -jar application.jar  -DappConfig=dev.properties it is failing the replace appConfig with dev.properties.

Comment: How are you passing the values? How is it failing?

Comment: @Andres i am passing the values from command line during runtime  with the command java -jar application.jar -DappConfig=dev.properties it is failing with the below reason

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${appConfig}] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `${spring.profiles.active}` and name the properties files accordingly to access them, e.g.:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

This way, you can have `dev.properties`, `stage.properties` etc present inside the class path and appropriate file will be picked up based on configured profile.

**Update**

You can pass the profile value as a command line argument while running the app, e.g. `java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar application.jar`

Comment: from where would you want me to pass the spring.profiles.active from ?

Comment: You can pass it as a command line argument, e.g. `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

Comment: redeployed the application still same issue

2017-04-16 15:56:13 INFO  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [${spring.profiles.active}.properties]
2017-04-16 15:56:13 WARN  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${spring.profiles.active}.properties] cannot be opened

Comment: @Vipin could you try this: `java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar application.jar`